# Get qualified name of an XML element and it's child nodes with C#

Tags: c#, xml, parsing, qualified-name, qnames

Edited:

I'm trying to accomplish three things here: get XmlNode Query, get the XmlNode QueryId and get the value of a:schemaLocation but the after parsing they end up as null. If I remove the qualified name from the XML, the C# bit works fine. How should I re-write my code?

XML:

```
    <soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:loc="localhost">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <loc:Service>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <loc:input>?</loc:input>
         <Query a:schemaLocation="http://www.xyz.com/xml.xsd" xmlns:payload="http://www.xyz.com" xmlns:a="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="loc4">
            <QueryId>Data</QueryId>
         </Query>
      </loc:Service>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

C#:

```
private NamespaceManager nsmgr;
private XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
private Stream receiveStream = new Stream(HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream);
private XmlNode Query, QueryId;

using (this.receiveStream){

using (StreamReader readStream = new StreamReader(this.receiveStream, Encoding.UTF8)){

     doc.Load(readStream);

     this.nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(this.doc.NameTable);
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("loc", "http://localhost");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "http://www.xyz.com/xml.xsd");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("payload", "http://www.xyz.com");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", this.doc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
     this.Query = doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:Query", this.nsmgr);
     this.QueryId= doc.SelectSingleNode("//x:QueryId", this.nsmgr);
     }
 }
```

Comment: The XML document contains all the necessary information when received but the code above doesn't parse the values "Query" and "QueryId" to their respected XmlNodes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you go...

```
XmlDocument xDoc = new XmlDocument();
xDoc.Load("Query.xml");

XmlNamespaceManager xnm = new XmlNamespaceManager(xDoc.NameTable);
xnm.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "loc");
xnm.AddNamespace("payload", "loc2");
xnm.AddNamespace("a", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance");
xnm.AddNamespace("x", xDoc.DocumentElement.NamespaceURI);
```

**Inner Text For Query:**

```
xDoc.SelectNodes("//x:Query", xnm)[0].InnerText
```

**Inner Text For QueryId:**

```
xDoc.SelectNodes("//x:QueryId", xnm)[0].InnerText
```

**a:schemaLocation Attribute:**

```
string namespaceURI = xnm.GetNamespacesInScope(XmlNamespaceScope.Local).FirstOrDefault(el => string.Equals(el.Key, "a")).Value;
var x = xDoc.DocumentElement.Attributes["schemaLocation", namespaceURI].Value;
```

Comment: The nodes are still empty. I modified my post to just grab the nodes. Any idea what's still going wrong?

Comment: @tomtomssi - I tried this code and could see it fetching results. Can you post the code (from your code file) using which you are trying to extract InnerText and attribute values?

Comment: I modified the code from the previous example. I removed the InnerText bits because the problem lies with the nodes. I'm using the code above to try to extract the nodes "Query" and "QueryId" but they end up empty.

Comment: Modified the XML, too

Comment: Also you need to add to the namespace table, the namespaces _soapenv_ and _loc_

Comment: Made the changes but its still empty. Any clue as to why?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple solution I came up with:

Removed the following lines:

```
 this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("soapenv", "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("loc", "http://localhost");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("schemaLocation", "http://www.xyz.com/xml.xsd");
     this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("payload", "http://www.xyz.com");
```

Modified:

```
this.nsmgr.AddNamespace("x", "loc4");
```

Finding the value of a:schemaLocation worked as suggested by Prash.